# Dynamic Object Key in Request Body in Nest JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, nestjs

I'm a beginner in Nest JS and I want to know if it is possible to have a dynamic object key in the request body? Something like this:

```
"123456":{
   "item 1": "etc",
   "item 2": "etc2"
},
"7891011":{
   "item 3": "etc3",
   "item 4": "etc4"

}
```

The "123456" and "78901011" are dynamic (IDs that have already been stored in DB). My goal is to store "item 1": "etc" and "item 2": "etc2" in "123456" and "item 3": "etc3" and "item 4": "etc4" in "7891011".

Here is my POST so far:

```
@ApiBearerAuth()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
@Post('/documents/')
async uploadDocs(@Request() req,
@Body() docuId: UploadDocDto) {
console.log(req)
console.log(docuId)
}
```

I am not sure if I should make changes in my controller file or in my DTO file. This is just the content of my DTO file:

```
export class UploadDocDto {
@ApiPropertyOptional()
@IsObject()
docuId?: object;
}
```

I want to know if it is possible for docuId to be dynamic. I tried it right now but this is the error that I'm getting:

```
{
"statusCode": 400,
"message": "Unexpected token } in JSON at position 139",
"error": "Bad Request"
}
```

This is my sample request body:

```
{
 "ee5dd871-1fc6-45b9-a3ea-7519a7ae8b54": {
        "originalname": "BOR2316.pdf",
        "originalname": "BOR2316.pdf",
        "originalname": "BOR2316.pdf",
    }
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that will have the same problem as me, here is the answer:

```
export class YourDto {
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

This also works in Swagger. You're welcome!

Comment: Error message is pretty obvious! It's just a parsing issue.

Comment: You cannot use `class-validator` decorators and `swagger` decorators in this approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your request body. Do not use `,` after value of last key.
Also you have duplicated key It would be better if you remove it. 
Your request body should be something like this:

```
{
 "ee5dd871-1fc6-45b9-a3ea-7519a7ae8b54": {
        "originalname": "BOR2316.pdf",
        "originalname": "BOR2316.pdf"
    }
}
```